# How to disable automatically adding a closing curly brace or bracket insertion in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to turn off automatically adding a closing curly brace in VS Code? I've gone through the editor settings one by one and turned off everything that was related to formatting, but there was nothing I saw specifically for this.

For example, when I type something like

```
function()
{
```

VS Code immediately adds `}` so that I end up with

```
function()
{}
```

Then, I press enter, and it has automatically indented the cursor.  I don't want it to do any of that.  I don't want it to auto insert any closing character or any indentations.  I basically just want it to stop helping me and let me type the way I want to type.  But I cannot figure out if there is any setting for this?

Comment: Not Alone, too often this has created bugs in my code.

Comment: Related: [Visual Studio Code disable auto-quote](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48714304/4975230), for those of you that are looking to disable all of the automatic behavior.

Comment: thank you for posting this question. I really like VSCode, but I can not understand a world where a development studio has "do things for you features" that are so hard to figure out how to turn off. How about authors of IDEs start adding "auto stop doing things for me" modes?

Comment: They have to throw the kitchen sink against the wall and see what gets hailed as innovation. Some things work great (multiple cursors) and other things are useless bling (minimap). 25 years ago we used IDEs without intellisense, autocompile, and even color coding.

Comment: Annoying as hell, I also disabled the auto-closing quotes and HTML tags `"editor.autoClosingQuotes": "never", "html.autoClosingTags": false`

Comment: "I'm probably the only person in the word " -> With the advent of tools like Copilot, I think you may not be as alone as you think on this regard. thanks for asking this question.

Comment: @DavidJeske as a busy developer, I find that the "do things for you" features save me valuable time. I don't have to ensure there are no missing closures, and I don't have to format code manually. If there's any feature that annoys me, it's easy enough to turn off or adjust.

Comment: Guys, shortly, it will not only auto-close brackets but also auto-complete your code, write your code, and fire you :)

Answer (score 199, accepted):

For new versions of vscode:

Open *Settings* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>), search for "autoClosingBrackets" and select "never" from the dropdown.

Or, for users who prefer to configure the settings via text editor, [open the settings file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65909052/332936), `settings.json` and add:

```
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": "never"
```

You can also do this in a language-specific way by

```
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "never"
}
```

`"always"`, `"languageDefined"`, and `"beforeWhitespace"` are the new additional options.

[image: vscode curly braces settings]

---

**[Previous, now inaccurate, setting.]**

> // Controls if the editor should automatically close brackets after opening them

```
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": false,
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is great -- not sure how I missed it.  I swear I went through the file line by line.  Guess I wasn't as careful as I thought.

Now... is there a way to disable auto indentation as well?  After typing an opening curly brace and hitting enter, it auto indents for me.  This is annoying b/c I hit tab by habit and then I end up with two tabs.

Comment: Is there anything for parentheses? I can't find it.

Comment: When I change the value to `"never"` (new options added later than the original answer - see above) I do not get parentheses automatically closed.  Try `"never"` instead of `"false"`.

Comment: If you disabled these settings, it's likely you'll also want to set `editor.autoSurround` to `"never"`.

Comment: I was expecting a settings page like in Visual Studio. Where do you type this?

Comment: On Mac (it's what I have) you open the Preferences panel
Then you enter "autocomplete" on the box to search settings
Then you will find (I'm working with Python) Python>Autocomplete blah
Then you click the "Edit in settings.json"

Comment: @Mark is there any way to temporarily disable these with a keyboard shortcut or keyboard modifier? I don't want to disable it permanently using the preference, but just do so temporarily for one instance every now and then.

Comment: For anyone looking, you type this in this file: `.vscode\settings.json`. If you don't have this file yet, create it, and type `{` and `}`. You paste the content above between those curly brackets. Formatting with some newlines and tabs is off course allowed as in any json file.

Answer (score 6):

Settings -> lookup "brackets" -> Editor: Auto Closing Brackets -> Never