# Prevent auto-closing tag (<>)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Typing `<` automatically results in `<>` in vscode. That is resulting in a problem to me when I use [auto-close-tag plugin](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-auto-close-tag), because it only works when I close this by myself (i.e., I need to close `<div` by myself to result in `<div></div>`).

So I need to disable this behavior. How can I do that?

**vscode 1.17.2**

Comment: Typing <  should not result in <>, so you "may" have a conflict with your auto-close-plugin because after that plugin was released VSCode has the same auto-close behavior built in for some languages, including html.  So you don't need the plugin.  Try disabling it and see if the unwanted behavior goes away.  If you still want to disable VSCode's auto-closing, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46470363/disable-automatic-curly-brace-insertion-in-vscode?rq=1  And see   "html.autoClosingTags": true,  You could set that to false.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The problem are `html.erb` files. In `html` the built-in autocomplete tags are working fine, but I'm having a hard time to deal with erb in vscode.