# Visual Studio Code disable auto-quote

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I disable the auto-quotes feature?

When I hit the ' or " key, I do not EVER want it to automatically insert another one anywhere. No matter how smart they make it, it just comes across to me as "unpredictable" and distracts me from what I'm trying to do.

I type over 100 wpm, I really don't need help hitting the ' or " key.

I have tried the following settings, but none of them have disabled this undesired behavior:

```
{
    "editor.autoClosingBrackets": false,
    "editor.wordWrap": "off",
    "html.autoClosingTags": false,
    "editor.formatOnType": false,
    "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",
}
```

Comment: Related: [How to disable automatically adding a closing curly brace or bracket insertion in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46470363/how-to-disable-automatically-adding-a-closing-curly-brace-or-bracket-insertion-i)

Comment: I think  Text editors should never enable features like this and let user enable if they want.  Even Microsoft likes crazy features in new products. Very annoying to say the least

Comment: I also had to disable "HTML: Auto Create Quotes".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Edit: from [vscode 1.27.0](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_27#_auto-closing-surrounding-characters)
>
> ```js
> "editor.autoClosingQuotes": "never",
> "editor.autoSurround": "never",// When the word is selected
> ```

I guess you can "type" them instead like this (`keybindings.json`):

```json
{
    "key": "'",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "'"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
},
```

Comment: Unlike the `"editor.autoClosingQuotes": "never"` setting, this also works when a word is selected and a quote key is pressed.

Comment: I can see that the default is languageDefined, but how do we define it for a language?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_languagespecific-editor-settings

Answer (score 43):

Put this in your user settings:

```
"editor.autoClosingQuotes": "never"
```

Comment: Where are the "user settings"?

Comment: @Bitterblue, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-can-i-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file) describes how to open json settings files.

Comment: To edit the JSON user settings file press **F1** or **Ctrl** + **Shift** + **P** and search for "**Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)**".

Answer (score 17):

In addition to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48714796/1543677), I also had to disable "HTML: Auto Create Quotes" in preferences (search for "Quote")

Comment: Very useful; was irritating having quotation marks auto-inserted when writing Angular templates etc

Comment: I second that. Auto putting anything my code while I'm typing is .... annoying. I don't know why they thought that was a good idea.

Comment: Thank you. This is the one that was always causing me issues.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a GUI-How-To-Change it:

1. Open the Settings-Dialog:

   - Press `Strg + ,` or Navigate with mouse to `File | Settings`
2. Change the Value of:

   - `editor.autoClosingQuotes` to the desired `never`
3. Thats it, no step 3 - only upvote my screenshot-answer..

[image: Change Setting via the GUI]

Comment: This is the first half of the full solution. This link shows the second half as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48714796/4402572

Answer (score 5):

1. Open Settings (File -> Preferences -> **Settings**) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Comma</kbd>
2. Search for **"editor close"**
3. You should find "Auto Closing Brackets" and "Auto Closing Quotes".
4. Change them to **"never ever"**!

Answer (score 3):

File > Preferences > Settings > type "quote" in search box

Answer (score 1):

add this to settings.json

```
"[scheme]": {
    "editor.autoClosingQuotes": "never"
},
```

Comment: This is very similar to the top-voted, accepted answer. It does offer more context as well as the file name, so it’s not identical, but it might make more sense as a comment or even suggested edit than a new standalone answer.