# how to setting vscode Javasript closing bracket

Tags: javascript, indentation, visual-studio-code, brackets

I've been working with javascript for a few months, but I feel hard to read the code easily. I like the way python use indentation instead of a bracket, its easier to read. So I tried to copy the typing pattern, but its tiring to correct the closing bracket (pressing backspace) every time I press enter when creating now function.
here I attach a snippet of what I trying to do automatically using vscode. Is there any way to do that by Preferences > Setting?

```js
// I try to copy python pattern
var webvile = {
 make: "webvile motors",
 model: "web"}
var chevy = {
 make: "chevy",
 model: "bel air"}
var fiat = {
 make: "fiat",
 model: "500"}
var cadilac = {
 make: "cadilac",
 model: "something"}

//when I press enter, closing bracket go 2 lines instead of one
var cadilac2 = {
 //code always starts here
}

//what I want is this (automatically)
var cadilac2 = {
 //the closing bracket is here --> }
```

Comment: The question says Visual Studio but the tag says Visual Studio Code settings. Two different products.

Comment: is it? well, I mean VScode then. thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46470363/disable-automatic-curly-brace-or-bracket-insertion-in-vscode

Comment: not exactly what I'm looking for, but its help. thanks