# VS Code wont let be type a closing curly brace

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is a small problem that has been annoying me for some time now.  VS Code will not let me type the `}` symbol.  If I type `{`, it will autocomplete with a closing curly brace, but then if I remove the opening curly brace, the closing brace will also be removed.  I have to get around this by copy and pasting the closing brace.

Is there a setting or caused by my formatter?  I am using Prettier (Like everyone else who uses VS Code) as my formatter.

Comment: Why not just type `}`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [disable automatic curly brace or bracket insertion in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46470363/disable-automatic-curly-brace-or-bracket-insertion-in-vscode)

Comment: that closing brace `}` shown after typing `{` is not added permanently only when you move the cursor to a different location but backspace or type `}`, if you type `{` and ArrowRight it is put in there permanent, try it with a selection of `({[` opening braces and backspace a few