# How to disable prettier auto adding brackets?

Tags: prettier

I'm using javascript, when I typing a async code like
`fn().then().catch(e=>console.log(e))`, my prettier always add brackets at the catch function like `fn().then().catch((e)=>console.log(e))`.
Is there any way to disable this behavior?

Comment: What brackets are you talking about?

Comment: You mean around the parameter (e)? Why do you insist on  removing that. It is good for readability

Comment: I think no brackets around a function with only one parameter is easier to write and read

Comment: Sorry, I found that has nothing to do about VSCode, It's because my prettier format config

Comment: This is what I want, thank you guys. https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#arrow-function-parentheses

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I see that by "brackets" you mean "parentheses".

This option is configurable using `arrow-function-parentheses`. [Documentation](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#arrow-function-parentheses)

In your case, you want:

```
arrowParens: "avoid"
```

Answer (score -1):

in vs code `Settings` and search for `Brackets` then set value to `never` for this option: **Auto Closing Brackets**.

Similarly you can add "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "never" in settings.json page.

Read more here:
[How to disable automatically adding a closing curly brace or bracket insertion in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46470363/how-to-disable-automatically-adding-a-closing-curly-brace-or-bracket-insertion-i)

Also, please provide complete details and focus on searching through SO links for any query first then if your question is not asked then only add your question.
Good luck!!

Comment: This is not what I want, thanks anyway